# Spring Boot MyBatis Create Table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mybatis

New to MyBatis, earlier used SpringBoot + JPA, now trying to use SpringBoot + MyBatis,
In JPA, we can create a table to Database(if not present) like -

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
public class ActivityDao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "optimized-sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "name_ko")
    private String nameKO;
}
```

Do MyBatis has anything similar like this?

Which will crate a table, if it does not exists in the Database?

Comment: I already have dependents of 

implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.0"

implementation "org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.3.0"

Comment: If you are asking if MyBatis implicitly executes `CREATE TABLE` statement, the answer is "no".